# Encontrar el máximo de una función en python

Tags: python

Dada una función tal que:

```
y = -(x-0.4)**2+10
```

Encontrar su máximo. Necesito alguna guía para utilizar la derivación en python ya que no me ha quedado claro como usar ciertas librerias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que no dices que librerías estás usando, y dado que la ecuación que tienes esta en forma simbólica te sugiero usar `sympy`.

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
y = -(x-0.4)**2+10
dy = diff(y)
print(dy)
sol = solve(dy)
print(sol)
```

Salida:

```
-2*x + 0.8
[0.400000000000000]
```

Comment: Sería bueno que los que coloquen negativo comenten el porqué, para mejorar el post

Comment: Estás igualando a 0 la primer derivada, lo que te da candidatos para máximos, pero me parece que también incluye mínimos

Comment: Lo que el pidio en el post es calcular la derivada con alguna librería y dio el ejemplo de una función, yo respondí respecto a ello, yo espero que el usuario del post mejore su pregunta para mejorar la respuesta

Comment: Quizás sería bueno aclararlo en la respuesta, de modo que alguien que lea el título "**Encontrar el máximo de una función en Python**" entienda que esto no responde al título, sino que sólo son los candidatos

Comment: @Mariano por eso puse considerando....

Comment: Eso explica por qué estás utilizando SymPy, no que este código no devuelve exclusivamente los máximos